# What can I do when Ubuntu 16.10 freezes?

Tags: 16.10, freeze, fsck

Ubuntu froze while I was saving an image from the Chromium browser. I have a small bit of unsaved work I'd like to save , but it's not terribly important. Mostly I'd like to know how to recover from this scenario.

The graphics appear to be frozen while the mouse remains movable. I've attempted to switch to another TTY. When I do this, I am presented with text of the form

```
/dev/sda1: clean 1039140/7036928 files, 25053986/28140800 blocks
```

There's no terminal login displayed. I can see this same message when I go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, +<kbd>F3</kbd>, +<kbd>F4</kbd>, +<kbd>F5</kbd> and +<kbd>F6</kbd>.

What should I try?

Comment: By *what should I try?*, you mean to go back to normal state, right? Not simply terminate

Comment: @M.Becerra Sure. Rebooting is straightforward. I am interested in things to try in case of needing to recover unsaved data or needing to pick up a calculation process that has been running for a long time.

Comment: Run a SSH server and log in remotely. You may not be able to revive the screen, but you may see whether processes have finished, etc. Killing the X server remotely will start up a new session faster than a hard reboot will.